# plot a curve for each parameter in a figure by recalling mat file

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am doing something similar to the following example:

```
t=linspace(0,1);
z=rand(1);
theta=pi*rand(1);
a_range=[1,2,3];
for nplot=1:3
   a=a_range(nplot);

    x=z*t.^2+a*sin(theta);

end

fname=['xsin.mat'];
save(fname)
```

the parameter *a* has three different values. For each value of *a*, I want to plot the function in one single figure. So at the end I will have three figures. I can do it using subplot but this will generate three plots in one figure which is not what I want.

In a new script, I load the mat file:

```
load('xsin.mat')

for nplot=1:3

figure(nplot)
plot(t,x)
end
```

but I get one figure not three as I should have. I mean for a=1, I should plot the curve in figure 1; for a=2, I should plot the curve in figure 2 and so on. How can I do this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem. If I add `figure(nplot); plot(t,x)` to the end of the loop in you first code I get 3 figures as expected.

Comment: Keep in mind that you only save your last `x` to _xsin.mat_, so if you load it and then plot you'll get three identical plots (in 3 different figures)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting `x` in every iteration; you could modify your code by saving each `x` for the respective `nplot` in a separate column of a matrix `X` (with minimal changes to your code):

```
t=linspace(0,1);
z=rand(1);
theta=pi*rand(1);
a_range=[1,2,3];

X = NaN(length(t), length(a_range));  % Create matrix to hold x values

for nplot=1:3
   a = a_range(nplot);
   x = z * t.^2 + a * sin(theta);
   X(:,nplot) = x;  % Store x in column of X
end

fname=['xsin.mat'];
save(fname)
```

Then, to create the figures:

```
load('xsin.mat')

for nplot=1:3
   x = X(:,nplot);  % Retrieve x from column of X
   figure(nplot)
   plot(t,x)
end
```

Comment: Thank you for correcting my code and answering my question. One question left, t and x are vectors of length 1 by 100. If I want to run the simulation for 50 times then take the average over the simulation, the average of x will be a vector of 1 by 50 which I can not plot against time t. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: @David, is `mean(X, 2)` what you are looking for? Also, you are currently drawing `z`, `theta` only once for all `a` – is that what you want, or do you want new draws for every iteration?

Comment: Thank you quick response. I thought it is better to explain what I need in detail so I post a question on the link: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41623167/compute-the-average-over-simulation-for-different-parameters-values]

Comment: @David, I believe that my suggestion solves the problem you have posted in the other question – how does `mean(X, 2)` not do exactly that?

Comment: Does not mean(X,2) compute the average directly over time? I am looking for first run 50 simulations, then take their average and plot it against time.

Comment: @David, that depends on what your time dimension is – if, as in the code above, `t` is time and `nplot` the running iteration of the simulation, then `mean(X, 2)` averages over the simulations (not over time). What happens if you try it out?

Comment: The nplot is not the running iteration for the simulation. As I pointed out early that I need to compute the average of the 50 simulations for every choice of the parameter a. So, inside the for loop of nplot, I need for loop to run 50 simulations. For example, nplot=1 so a=1 and I will run 50 simulations for the function x then take the mean over the simulation. Then for nplot=2 so a=2, I run the simulations again and compute their mean over the simulation. At the end, I will have three averages that I need to plot against time.

Comment: @David, I see. In this case, you could try to put another loop inside each `nplot` iteration with `Xsim(:,iter) = x` (where `iter` is the running variable, and then set `X(:, nplot) = mean(Xsim, 2)`. I hope this helps.