# compute the average over simulation for different parameters values

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am working on something similar to the following example:
I want to compute `<x(t)>` that is the average of a function `x(t)` over number of simulations. To do this, I generate the following code:

```
sim=50;% number of simulations 
t=linspace(0,1);% time interval

a_range=[1,2,3];% different values for the parameter a
b_range=[0,0.5,1];% different values for the parameter b
z=zeros(1,sim);
theta=zeros(1,sim);

for nplot=1:3
   a=a_range(nplot);
   b=b_range(nplot);
   average_x=zeros(nplot,sim);
   for i=1:sim
       z(i)=rand(1);% random number for every simulation
       theta(i)=pi*rand(1);% random number for every simulation    
    x=z(i)*t.^2+a*sin(theta(i))+b.*tan(theta(i));% the function

   end
   average_x(nplot,sim)=mean(x);% average over the number of simulations
end

fname=['xsin.mat'];
save(fname)
```

The time is a vector 1 by 100 and x is a vector 1 by 100, and average_x is 1 by 50. What I am looking for is to write a script to load the file and plot the average against time for different parameters a and b. So I want to write a code to generate three figures such that in figure 1 I will plot the average

```
plot(t,average_x)
```

for a=1 and b=0.

Then in figure 2 I will plot the average again but for a=2 and b=0.5 and so on. The problem is the dimension of time t and the average are not the same. How can I fix this problem and generate three distinct figures.

Comment: You want to plot 50 values against 100 values. This is impossible without choosing 50 values instead of 100 **or** interpolating the 50 values to 100.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I got your intention correctly, this is what you look for:

```
sim = 50;% number of simulations 
t = linspace(0,1);% time interval

a_range = [1,2,3];% different values for the parameter a
b_range = [0,0.5,1];% different values for the parameter b

% NO NEED TO GENERATE THE RANDOM NUMBERS ONE BY ONE:
theta = pi*rand(sim,1);% random number for every simulation
z = rand(sim,1); % random number for every simulation

% YOU SOULD INITIALIZE ALL YOUR VARIABLES OUTSIDE THE LOOPS:
x = zeros(sim,numel(t)); 
average_x = zeros(3,numel(t));% the mean accross simulations
% for average accros time use:
% average_x = zeros(3,sim);

for nplot=1:3
   a = a_range(nplot);
   b = b_range(nplot);
   for i=1:sim
       x(i,:) = z(i)*t.^2+a*sin(theta(i))+b.*tan(theta(i));% the function
   end
   average_x(nplot,:) = mean(x); % average over the number of simulations
   % average_x(nplot,:) = mean(x,2); % average accross time
end
% save the relevant variables:
save('results.mat','average_x','t')
```

In another file you can write:

```
load('results.mat')
for k = 1:size(average_x,1)
    figure(k)
    plot(t,average_x(k,:))
    title(['Parameter set ' num2str(k)])
    xlabel('Time')
    ylabel('mean x')
end
```

This is the plot in one figure (if you want then average over simulations):

[image: mean sim]

---

BTW, if you want to make your code more compact and fast, you can vectorize it, mainly using [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html). Here is a demonstration with your code:

```
% assuming all parameters are defined as above:
zt = bsxfun(@times,z,t.^2); % first part of the function 'z(i)*t.^2'
% second part of the function 'a*sin(theta(i)) + b.*tan(theta(i))':
ab = bsxfun(@times,a_range,sin(theta)) + bsxfun(@times,b_range,tan(theta));
% convert the second part to the right dimensions and size:
ab = repmat(reshape(ab,[],1,3),1,numel(t),1); 
x = bsxfun(@plus,zt,ab); % the function
average_x = squeeze(mean(x)); % take the mean by simulation
plot(t,average_x) % plot it all at once, as in the figure above
xlabel('Time')
ylabel('mean x')
```

Comment: Thank you for your post. If I get correct, figure 1 is the plot of the average over the simulation against time, i.e x-axis is time. So it should be plot(t,average_x). I get confuse when come to for loop. If you do not mind correct me if I am wrong: x(i,:) means for every simulation compute the function and store the value in row i. So you end the loop with x be 50 by 100. Then average_x(nplot,:) means for every nplot and over all columns compute the mean(x) and assign it to average_x(nplot,:). How can I tell that mean(x) computes the mean over the simulations?

Comment: I am looking for something like figure 1 but should not there be a randomness in the curve because the function and so the mean are defined in terms of random variables `z` and `theta`. Or is it true the mean of random function would be a smooth curve? Again, the code you wrote is what I am looking for and I waiting for how to save the file and then plot the average in different three figures.

Comment: The reason you don't see any randomness is that `z` and `theta` are 'constant' with respect to time and variable only between simulations. Since you average across simulations (i.e. you take 50 values per one timestep) all the different `z`s and `theta`s per timestep collapse into one value, and there is no randomness.